# Understanding data passing using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was reading

```
function myHandler(event) {
    alert(event.data.foo);
}

$("p").on("click", { foo: "bar" }, myHandler)
```

But I think I can do it by

```
  function myHandler(a) {
      alert(a);
  }
  $("p").on("click", function() { myHandler('bar') })
```

Why would I use event, what is event actually for, I also see many people use '`this`' and '`that`' in their code, but I can't understand what is it, why not just select elements by their name like `$('#something')`, that's what I usually do? Any tips on writing most simplify program codes? There are too many different methods but doing the same thing on coding.

Comment: Re-selecting via DOM lookups is pretty inefficient when jQuery hands you the relevant object as `this` anyway

Comment: `this` within the handler refers to the clicked element.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  The question is quite clear, except for the open-ended title, which I will edit in a moment.

Comment: @Brad reopend ..now please change the title

Comment: @NullPointer, Jack already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that there are more than one way of achieving the same thing, it depends on the situation.

The first code snippet does a few things in terms of semantics:

1. The function declaration makes it very clear that `myHandler` is not an ordinary function, but an event handler; this may not be important to you now, but it will be once you hand over code to someone else or you come back to your code in a few months time.
2. Because it's declared separately, it shows the intent that `myHandler` will be reused as well. I would imagine there will be more statements that will apply the same handler to other jQuery selectors.
3. Due to #1 and #2, auxilary data can no longer be passed in a normal fashion but needs to be passed via the `Event` as well.

Your own code snippet makes a compromise between generic code and simplicity; and there's no reason why it would blow up.

**To answer your other questions**

> Why would I use event?

You wouldn't in many cases; take this code for example, based on the most used feature of jQuery's event handling:

```
<a href="http://www.example.org">...</a>

$('a').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something beautiful
});
```

Here, the event `e` is passed to the click handler, and it then stops the browser from navigating to a link when the link is clicked. The same can be accomplished with this:

```
$('a').on('click', function() { 
    // do something beautiful
    return false;
});
```

Although the intent of above code is less obvious, it does the same thing without touching events at all.

> What is event actually for?

It encapsulates data about various user input, such as key presses, clicks, drags, etc. jQuery generalizes it and extends it with data passing capabilities. See also: [`Event object`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

> Why not just select elements by their name?

There's no authoritative answer here, but click handler code becomes more generic and maintainable when you use `this` to reference the clicked element (or selectors based on it to reference parent, siblings, etc.); if you ever need to add the same behaviour to other elements you don't have to write X different click handlers.